# Would this situation be considered plagiarism? - humanities assignment

Tags: plagiarism

Here is what happened.

In one of my humanities class, I had to do a project that involved creating exam questions from the reading material and explain why they a relevant in today’s society. In my rough drafts, I would write key points from the readings as a reference for writing my questions. One of the questions I chose was a true and false format for the definition of culture. I made it a false statement by switching the the word culture with civilization. I wrote the definition of culture from my professor’s presentation and underneath I wrote my own definition. Later in the day after I got home from work, I wrote the question into my final draft. I don’t know why this occurred maybe I was tired but when I was writing it into my final draft, I misread and included the professor’s definition rather than my own. I did not include in text citations; however, in the study guide we had to create, I included my professor’s name, the name of the presentation, and where I got the information. I sent an email to my professor, but it has been four days and he still hasn’t contacted me.

Comment: You did the right thing in informing your professor.  It's Sunday; one or maybe two of your four days are part of the weekend.  Try not to worry.  No answer is much more likely to mean all is well than that you are in difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard for me to see plagiarism here, since you say you used the professor's definition, which is clearly known to both of you.

Of course, it is up to the professor to judge and if the rules are ver strict then perhaps you will be called to account for it.

But you did the right thing in informing the professor of the issue. I'll just have to guess that you are safe.